# remove kendo grid default filter options

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The current filterable option is set as:

```
filterable:{operators:{string:{eq:"Equal to"}}},
```

which produces the following drop down

[image]

I wanted to remove the "AND" part so that the drop down looks like this

[image]

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the api documentation it shows you this here: [remove extra filter option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-filterable.extra)